# Install Android OS along with Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: grub2, android

I have Dual Boot of Windows and Ubuntu 11.10, I recently learned that it is possible to install Android OS on Laptops, I also learned that in such cases Android uses its own Bootloader, Now what i want is

- [Install Android](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22665/run-android-on-your-netbook-or-desktop/) Along with Ubu and Win.
- Use Grub/Burg as THE boot-loader.

and i was Unable to find info about second point in the internet, Help needed

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22665/run-android-on-your-netbook-or-desktop/

Comment: Even though this sounds wonderful there's one thing you should know, you won't have 3d acceleration, having said that everything but the home screens are going to be choppy, so this is just for the fun of it, but not for regular use.

Comment: I did whatever you mentioned but it won't worked.<br>
I did this in ubuntu 14.04.<br>
Nothing changed.<br>
I changed the lines according to my folder name i.e android-4.4-RC1.<br>
I also seen the disk number, i.e sda7 in my pc where android x86 is installed and edited set root=(hd0,7) and also did sudo update-grub atlast after making changes.<br>
No android part is shown in grub when i restarted..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming you will install android into it's own partition - for example `/dev/sda3` - if in doubt type `sudo fdisk -l` in a terminal.

When installing android and it asks you to install Grub - DON'T!

Next, boot into Ubuntu

Launch Nautilus and double click the Android device and note the name of the Android folder name

[image]

Next we need to add some custom grub entries:

```
menuentry "Android-x86 2.2 (MDPI)" {
set root=(hd0,4)
linux /android-2011-02-20/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-2011-02-20 DATA= DPI=160
initrd /android-2011-02-20/initrd.img
}

menuentry "Android-x86 2.2 (HDPI)" {
set root=(hd0,4)
linux /android-2011-02-20/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-2011-02-20 DATA= DPI=240
initrd /android-2011-02-20/initrd.img
}

menuentry "Android-x86 2.2 (VESA)" {
set root=(hd0,4)
linux /android-2011-02-20/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-2011-02-20 DATA= vga=788
initrd /android-2011-02-20/initrd.img
}

menuentry "Android-x86 2.2 (Debug mode)" {
set root=(hd0,4)
linux /android-2011-02-20/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode DEBUG=1 vga=788 SRC=/android-2011-02-20 DATA=
initrd /android-2011-02-20/initrd.img
}
```

In a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Copy and paste the above custom entries into gedit.

Search and replace `android-2011-02-20` with the android folder name - for example `android-2012-01-29`

Next you need to work out which hard-disk and partition you have install android.

I've installed Android-x86 on `sda3`, so I've searched and replaced `(hd0,4)` with `(hd0,3)` - `hd0` means the first hard disk (`sda`) and `3` is the partition and comes from `sda3`.

Hard disk naming starts with 0 so basically, `sda` is `hd0`, `sdb` is `hd1` and so on. Counting partitions doesn't start with `0`, so if you've installed Android x86 on let's say `sdb5`, you'd use `(hd1,5)`.

Save and close gedit

Finally update your grub configuration

`sudo update-grub`

[image]