# How to add android x86 item to GRUB list?

Tags: 11.10, grub2, dual-boot, android, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Android OS along with Ubuntu and Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99059/install-android-os-along-with-ubuntu-and-windows)

I have installed android from this [topic](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/android-x86-40-rc1-released-android-ice.html), and when it ask me if i want to install GRUB i say no as it is installed when i setup Ubuntu 11.10, but the android item didn't appear in the GRUB list so how to add it to GRUB ???

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/grub.d/40_custom
add:

```
menuentry "Android" {
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,HERE NUMBER OF PARTITION WITH YOUR ANDROID)'
linux /android-4.0-RC1/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=asus_laptop acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-4.0-RC1
initrd /android-4.0-RC1/initrd.img}
```