# Install Android emulator to play mobile game

Tags: 18.04, games, android, android-emulator

who from you can tell me what the best way and tools to install an android mobile app game ( freefire for example ) on my ubuntu 18.04 ? any android emulator to recommend ?

Answer (score 1):

Games like free fire and PUBG are supported in emulators only on windows. There is no android emulator available for Ubuntu.

But if you want to feel like playing on Desktop(Ubuntu). you can follow these steps :

1. Install screen share over USB like scrcpy (freeware)

   - In terminal run cmd **sudo snap install scrcpy**
   - Allow USB debugging in developer option
   - Then connect your android phone with laptop or desktop using USB
   - In terminal run cmd **scrcpy**
2. Install octopus from the app store for mapping keyboard on the screen.

Comment: Personally i use Android-x86 to play _free fire_ and other android apps. it works fine as triple boot with Ubuntu and windows. here is a method https://askubuntu.com/a/99683/1194692

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use [Android-x86](https://www.android-x86.org/download.html), free and reliable. you can install it as mentioned [here](https://www.fosslicious.com/2018/08/how-to-install-android-x86-on-ubuntu.html) or [here](https://linuxhint.com/install_android_dual_boot_linux/)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to feel the best gaming experience on ubuntu.

1. PHOENIX OS, Phoenix OS gives the better gaming experience than other
   ubuntu emulators.(free fire,pubg)
2. Downloading of Phoenix OS is little bit risky and harder.
3. But you follow the instructions on youtube makes the installation easier.
   (Phoenix OS gives better experience in windows than ubuntu,But you have no way to install windows on your laptop/computer then you continue with ubuntu)
4. Minimum systemspecs for downloading Phoenix OS
   -2GB RAM.
   -upto 16GB ROM.(internal space)
5. Youtube tutorial link:- https://youtu.be/vGn1ISy0KpI
6. click on the above link and see the tutorial vedio of downloading Phoenix OS.
7. watch the tutorial carefully and install phoenix os.
8. After install reboot your pc. and select phoenix in grub menu .your pc will
   open the phoenix os in second boot.
9. After opening Phoenix OS open playstore and download you game.
10. Having any doubts about installation and playing games.search more in youtube